# Does onPause() have to be executed after activity dies?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

When a activity dies due to the limit of memory, the activities will be destroyed according to their priority, say, a background activity (`onStop()` called) will be destroyed due the usage of memory, will `onDestroy()` be called, and to the extreme, when the foreground activity is destroyed due to the same kind of reason, how the lifecycle callback is called, and will `onPause()` always be called under all the circumstances?

Comment: `will onPause() always be called under all the circumstances?` That would be a better subject for your post then you have now.

Comment: onPause() will not be called when you call finish() from the same activity, and its the only situation when onPause() is not called

Comment: No it is not necessary that onPause() will be called always.. ..
As in this case if Activity is destroyed or application is being Crashed, Your application will stop responding, and you need to restart your app, i:e from onCreate method.. ..